# Can I keep "Leave game as group" checked by default?

Tags: overwatch

When playing Overwatch with friends, I sometimes forget to tick '*Leave game as group*' when exiting a game, which causes the group to disband.

**Is there a way to change the settings so '*Leave game as group*' is checked by default?**

[image: Leave game as group]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added in the [November 16, 2017 patch](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20759535818).

> Clicking the "leave game as group" checkbox will now remember your selection for future matches

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As Wrigglenite pointed out in [their answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315325/can-i-keep-leave-game-as-group-checked-by-default/323109#323109), this feature has now been implemented.

At the moment, it doesn't seem to be possible (I checked every options page multiple times) but you may suggest that feature in the [Overwatch Forums](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/).